# How to convert a .ovpn file to a .conf for OpenVPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, arch-linux, openvpn

A VPN provider gives .ovpn files that contain the configuration necessary to connect to a VPN server using the command : `openvpn name.ovpn`

However using this command isn't very clean since it uses a shell that you can't close anymore if you want to keep the connection. Instead I'd like to be controlling the openvpn connection through systemd but it is my understanding that I first need to create a `name.conf` file in `/etc/openvpn` so I can then call the command `systemctl enable openvpn@name.service` which would be handy since it would connect to the VPN server at startup.

How to go from the .ovpn config file to `/etc/openvpn/name.conf` ?

Comment: In newer version put file in `/etc/openvpn/client/` dir

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's the same thing, you can basically just rename the `.ovpn`file into `.conf`and move it into `/etc/openvpn`

Comment: And vice-versa! I had the inverse problem with the latest OpenVPN Connect on Mac (version 3), which reads only .ovpn file and mine was a .conf file, I renamed it and it worked. Aren't these filename-extension issues ridiculous?